# API Manager Plugin - logins with usernames with @ (example username@somewhere.com)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-governance-registry

We are attempting to use the API Manager plugins for GREG (API Store and API Publisher).  We noticed that if our user accounts are anything with an @something.com, then the API Publisher assumes that you are using a tenant and fires code against a non-existing file in the jaggery app and this is a tenant aware function in greg-landing.jag.

```
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Requested resource /modules/tenant-api.js cannot be found (/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/pages/greg-landing.jag#9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.extensions.app.greg_publisher.pages.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/pages/greg-landing.jag:9)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.extensions.app.greg_publisher.pages.c0.call(/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/pages/greg-landing.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.c1._c_anonymous_19(/publisher/modules/publisher.js:409)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.c1.call(/publisher/modules/publisher.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<store>.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_18(<store>/scripts/server.js:318)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<store>.scripts.c0.call(<store>/scripts/server.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.c1._c_anonymous_18(/publisher/modules/publisher.js:404)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.c1.call(/publisher/modules/publisher.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.extensions.app.greg_publisher.pages.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/pages/greg-landing.jag:3)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.extensions.app.greg_publisher.pages.c0.call(/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/pages/greg-landing.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.extensions.app.greg_publisher.pages.c0.exec(/publisher/extensions/app/greg_publisher/pages/greg-landing.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        ... 57 more Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Requested resource /modules/tenant-api.js cannot be found
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.getScriptLastModified(WebAppManager.java:766)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.executeScript(WebAppManager.java:300)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.require(WebAppManager.java:358)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        ... 78 more
```

We checked against Enterprise Store and it also lacked the file refernced in the error.

Finally, in the full-blown API install, the fix for this was to update the user-mgt.xml with

```
<Property name="UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9@._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
```

Are there any configurations that we are missing to avoid this?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: did you checked the steps in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS460/Email+Authentication? did you uncomment the EnableEmailUserName config in carbon.xml as the documentation points.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  We indeed have the <EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName> setting in both our 5.0.1 GREG instance (running the API Publisher/Store plugins) and our 5.0.0 IS instance.

Answer (score 2):

I thing you miss to Configure this file
- [AM_Home]/repository/conf/carbon.xml

```
    <EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>
```